# Infinite loop on animate

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need a div to slide out the left of the screen and when the width is done it must restart. e.g. like its running in a circle endlessly.

I have managed to find this after searching stackoverflow.

```
jQuery(".slide-inner").animate({left: -9913}, 80000, 'linear');
```

9913 being the current width of my div in px. right now it just finishes the 9913 width and then ends the animation, it need to start over again without showing white space e.g. when it hits the final pixel in 9913 it must start from 1px all over again.

My html:

```
<div class="slide-inner">
<div class="one ani"></div>
<div class="two ani"></div>
<div class="three ani"></div>   
<div class="four ani"></div>
<div class="five ani"></div>
<div class="six ani"></div>
</div>
```

Ignore the elements inside .slide-inner. Those are just absolute position divs that i am using with css3 to light up the slider at keypoints.

EDIT:

```
var animate = function() {
  $(".slide-inner").animate({left: -9913}, 80000, 'linear', function() {
  $(this).css('left', 1);
  animate();
 });
}
animate();
```

Problem with above code is left', 1) needs to be responsive so i cant put in there -1920 and then on browser resize it will not function like it should?

Comment: Maybe providing a JSFiddle would help

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want is a callback for `animate()`, combined with a function that performs the animation i.e. a recursive function.

```
var animate = function() {
  $(".slide-inner").animate({left: -9913}, 80000, 'linear', function() {
    $(this).css('left', 1);
    animate();
  });
}
animate();
```

I've thrown together a really basic fiddle to demonstrate this technique: http://jsfiddle.net/6mfCx/

Comment: Do we not get stack overflows in javascript? I have never looked into it before to be honest.

Comment: @musefan I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Hey, the code you provided me above works but it first shows the entire width of the parent div with white background at the end of the animation, then starts over, i basically want it to look like it never ends, so the at the end of 9913, the first px needs to be starting again at the moment it first slides for e.g. width of div on fullscreen being 1920px before it starts over, it needs to be responsive as the parent div is currently set at 100% width.

Comment: You are using a recursive technique, with no condition to break it. animate calls animate which calls animate... and on for eternity, or until the browser breaks?

Comment: @Musefan Oh I get you. There's an 8 second delay between each iteration, so I don't see it exhausting the browser's memory.

Comment: @user2810762 Sorry, I'm having difficulty deciphering that comment! My solution does what you asked for, which is "when it hits the final pixel in 9913 it must start from 1px all over again". If you want the animation to restart at a position other than left:1px then you can simply change $(this).css('left', 1); in my code to another value.

Comment: I have uploaded you code in action here: dreamsynk.com/rosewater. Jump down to gallery and watch as its ending there is just white space. I wish i didnt have to do this animation or that slider at all. In my opinion it looks ugly and is spoiling my design, but client wants this. Give it 5 minutes, its still uploading.

Comment: Try making .slide-inner wider, so that the background image has room to repeat.

Comment: Thanks m8, double thumbs up. I wish i could up you but need 15 rep for that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use `background-image` & `background-repeat:repeat-x;` for your div. Then you can animate `background-position` property of div & get desired effect.

Suppose your div width is 1920px, then animate from `background-position:0px 0px` to `background-position:-1920px 0px;`.

```
function animate() {
  $(".slide-inner").animate({'background-position':'0px -1920px'}, 80000, 'linear', function() {
    $(this).css('background-position','0px 0px');
    animate();
  });
}
animate();
```